# Observables chain with RXJS with passing parameters

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to use nice chaining like below:

```
this.loginService.login() //returns token
            .flatMap(this.userService.setToken(token))
            .flatMap(this.userService.getCurrentUserData()) //returns data
            .flatMap(this.userService.setCurrentUserData(data))
            .subscribe(

            )
```

but I need to pass parameters from one observable to another. How to do it with chaining? Maybe there is a better solution to have pretty code without a big tree of observables?

Regards

Comment: Can you be more specific what you're trying to achieve? Now it looks like you don't need to work with results from the previous Observables at all which suggests you could use `forkJoin`. But I guess that's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.loginService.login() //returns token
      .flatMap((loginData)=>this.userService.setToken(token,loginData)) // passing data
```

And continue for the rest of them